# Cannot read token on Home - Authorization: Bearer undefined

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, jwt, postman

Hi I am working on authentication in login form, after I enter the correct credentials on login form, I get the token but when I go to the Home component, wherein my componentdidmount is located,
gives me error that my `Authorization: Bearer undefined` and `401 UnAuthorize`

Login Component

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data ={
            username:this.username,
            password: this.password
        }
        
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth',data)
         .then(res=>{
             console.log(res)
             localStorage.setItem('token',res.data.token);
         })
         .catch(err=>{
             console.log(err)
         })
    };
```

Home Component

```
 componentDidMount(){
        const config ={
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
               
            }
        };
        
        
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/user',config)
            .then(
                res=> {
                    console.log(res);
                },
                err =>{
                    console.log(err);
                }
                  
            )
    }
```

Comment: can you show `console.log(res)`?

Comment: Console :GET http://localhost:5000/api/user 401 (Unauthorized)
|| Network: Authorization: Bearer undefined

Comment: I mean console.log before `localStorage.setItem('token',res.data.token);`

Comment: data: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZ…QzNn0.ObXGmM19BXSI33gND0AkuULK3fNJZXaHlzBqW2eZ970", status: 200, statusText: "OK"

Answer (score 0):

I saw the `res` is an object with key `data` is token. So you just update like this:

`localStorage.setItem('token',res.data);`

Comment: I change and it reads the bearer token now! but still showing me 401 Unauthorize error

Comment: Is `localStorage.getItem(...)` an async method? Before calling `axios.get` verify what's in the `config` variable.

Comment: confi variable is where the header is.